# What was it when it came for a third time?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

For the first time it happened one night as `0025316` and after forty-one years it flew over the earlier one as `0073486`.

What was it when it broke the silence for the last time after sixteen years?

Comment: A well-constructed question.  I like how the puzzle text helps confirm the solution after the fact (I didn't notice it until I re-read the question after finding the answer).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It was

> **0102926**: [The Silence of the Lambs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102926/)

The numbers in the question are

> [IMDB](http://imdb.com) codes for movies:
>
>  **0025316**: [It Happened One Night](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025316/) (1934)
>  **0073486**: [One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073486/) (1975)
>
>  The unique thing about these movies is that they won [Academy Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Awards) in all of the five major categories (Best Picture, Best Actor, Best Actress, Best Director, and Adapted Screenplay).
>
>   To date, only one other film has done the same, 16 years after *Cuckoo's Nest*, in 1991:  *[The Silence of the Lambs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silence_of_the_Lambs_(film))*.

Comment: I *knew* it had something to do with OFOTCN! :-D Call it a hunch. I even looked up that book to see if it was part of a trilogy or something.

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> 0102926

I see I have a different answer than @GentlePurpleRain, but for the same reason.

> They are IMDB IDs of the three films that have won the Big Five Oscars (Best Picture, Best Director, Best Actor, Best Actress, and Best Screenplay).

.

> [It Happened One Night (1934)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025316/)

.

> [One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest (1975)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073486/)

.

> [The Silence of the Lambs (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102926/)